# Is it possible to generate a SQL Database from a JSON file?

Tags: mysql, json, database

Well I have a database in JSON format, originally generated from an exel file, but I want to modernize my database and export it into a MySQl database. This is the JSON structure:

```
[
         {
            "NOMBRE": "TEST",
            "ESPECIALIDAD": "TEST",
            "ESPECIALIDAD2": "TEST PEDIATRICA",
            "ESPECIALIDAD3": "",
            "CEL": "2222009374947478474777",
           etc.....
        }, {
            "NOMBRE": "TEST",
            etc.....
        }
]
```

If this is not possible or difficult, Its a better option to directly export the exel file into MySQL?

Comment: You also need the column types, which unfortunately JSON doesn't really excel at indicating. e.g. is the string a `VARCHAR(255)` or `VARCHAR(127)` or `TEXT`...etc? So first thing you need to do is to create the table structure first. Then parse it with any programming language of your choice and import into database

Comment: If you still have the Excel file you better export it as `csv` then (after you create the table in the database) use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import it into MySQL. If you don't have the Excel file any more then use another method to generate the `csv` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql: You will have to convert it to an CSV, use excel to write SQL, or write some import procedure.
With MariaDB you could skip this entirely and use the JSON column format:
 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/column_json/

Upgrading MySQL to MariaDB is easy and quick. It gets you a little bit of a performance increase + this nice JSON column format (and a few more).